# How to redirect controller from same module

Tags: php, yii

> I have one module that is OfficeModule. In OfficeModule I have two
> controller BranchController and BranchTypeController. And two model
> BranchModel and BranchTypeModel. And also two view file. Files path
> are like that:
>
> protected\modules\office\controllers\branchController.php
>
> protected\modules\office\controllers\branchtypeController.php
>
> protected\modules\office\models\Branch.php
>
> protected\modules\office\models\BranchType.php
>
> I have one Module file: protected\modules\office\OfficeModule.php
>
> When I call from url
> projectname.test.com/office/branch I want to redirect like that:
> projectname.test.com/office/branchtype. Now I am writing redirect() in
> OfficeModule.php within

```
public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action){
  $controller->redirect(array('../branchtype'));
}
```

But it doesn't work and can't redirect. Anyone please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

That's ok like that: :)

```
public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
{
  $getcontroller = Yii::app()->controller->id;
  if($getcontroller == 'branch'){
    $controller->redirect(array('/office/branchtype'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> ```
> $controller->redirect(array('branchtype/index'));
> ```

it's redirects to your module's controller `branchtype` and action `index`. And

> ```
> $controller->redirect(array('/branchtype/index'));
> ```

redirects to the app controller `branchtype` and action `index` (outside the module)